# How to open a terminal from Finder?

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-sierra

Within Finder, it would be sweet to have an "Open Terminal here" like in Linux Ubuntu. It should open a Terminal within the path Finder is currently pointing to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete this question, here is what I ended up doing:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20633/76512

This is not as convenient as on linux, but it's the closest I could get. If you have better options, feel free to post them. Sadly, the keyboard-shortcut for this "Service" did not work.

Comment: This was already answered in the duplicate question. Next time, please search a little before asking a question.

Comment: @slhck I found that one myself if I remember correctly, but it didn't satisfy me. Since this question is old now, I decided to write what I did, even though it's not that satisfying. You need 2 clicks, 2 menus and shortcuts do not work. I really hope that apple will do something better in the future. But ATM it doesn't seem possible to come any closer to what I asked for.